# nginx proxy proper config for returning everything including subpaths

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I need proper config for nginx proxy for returning everything, no matter what in another service by address localhost:8000.
Examples:

```
example.com               ->  localhost:8000
example.com/api/book      ->  localhost:8000/api/book
example.com/js/main.js    ->  localhost:8000/js/main.js
example.com/css/main.css  ->  localhost:8000/css/main.css
```

POST GET PUT DELETE no matter.
Is it possible to not specify every subpath and every file extentions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a simple config

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

This should pass the request as it is with same path, data and http method